# Is there a way to specify Custom Data for Azure VM Images?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to use Azure Management SDK for .Net to specify [custom data](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/21/custom-data-and-cloud-init-on-windows-azure/) for a specialized VM image I've created but cannot find a way.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157201.aspx) it seems that `CustomData` is a part of `WindowsProvisioningConfiguration` or `LinuxProvisioningConfiguration`. But it's also been specified in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Compute.Models.Role` that

```
    // Summary:
    //     Optional. Optional. The name of the VMImage from which this Role is to be
    //     created. If the OSDisk in the VMImage was Specialized, then no WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet
    //     or LinuxProvisioningConfigurationSet should be provided. No OSVirtualHardDisk
    //     or DataVirtualHardDisk should be specified when using this argument.
    public string VMImageName { get; set; }
```

I don't want to use generalized VM images because I've found that some configurations would be lost after using Sysprep so I want to use specialized VM images if possible. Is there a way to set custom data for specialized VM images?